# jquery mobile-vertically center two lines of button text

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar with 5 ui-btn with the following CSS rules (for vertically center :

```
#company_nav .ui-btn{
    height:28px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

The problem is that one of the ui-btn has 2 lines, and the other line get out from the button.
How  do I manage it?

here is the code:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="grey_bkgd nav-no-border ui-navbar" id="company_nav" role="navigation">
            <ul class="ui-grid-d ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                <li class="ui-block-a ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="one" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#one" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-b ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="two" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#two" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Products</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-c ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="recent" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#recent" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Employees</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-d ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="recent" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false"><a href="#recent" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Followers</a></li>
                <li class="ui-block-e ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="activity" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false"><a href="#activity" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5">Recent<br>activities</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not an elegant solution, but is a workaround:

```
#company_nav .ui-btn{
    height:28px;    
    line-height:28px;
}

#company_nav li:last-child .ui-btn{
    line-height:14px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/osxct2j8/)